# Ascending and Decending ORDER BY clauses in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I working on these problems for a class I"m taking, but this one has me stumped. Here is the problem:

--Using the AUTHOR table, write a query that will list all information about authors
--whose first name ends with an “A”. Put the results in descending order of last name, 
--and then ascending order by first name. This should be done using a single query.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM author
WHERE(fname LIKE '%A')
ORDER BY lname DESC, fname ASC;
```

However all I get in the result is the information ordered by last name descending. First name ascending doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing? Using Oracle Express 10G, if it matters.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expect and actual output?  The `fname ASC` order by will only ever be applicable if 2 or more authors have the same last name.

Comment: The first name ascending only takes effect if two authors have the same last name.

Comment: Actually, I think you all can disregard this question. I wasn't completely sure what I was looking at when I first viewed the results. For some reason, I was expecting two lists, one showing descending and one showing ascending. After doing a little more research and finding that the first name ascending would only take effect if the authors shared the same last name, I realized I had the right code for what I was doing after all.

Comment: You can delete it if it's no bueno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query. All you have to do is just pay attention to the data :-)
Here is how you would interpret your data output:

```
--------------+--------------
zzz           | john
zza           | adam 
zaa           | bob
ccc           | jack
ccc           | john
cca           | mike
```

So, ordering works just you instruct Oracle - lname desc, fname acs, but you need to realize that `fname asc` comes in a picture once `lname desc` is processed. In other words: `ZZZ` comes before `ZZA` , but once `CCC` is ordered then and only then `jack` comes before `john` .